# Number of optional arguments for a method in Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Not sure that there is an answer for this but hope somebody know. What I am trying is to get number of optional arguments for a Method in Ruby 1.8.7. `Method#arity` will not work since it returns `-n-1`, where `n` is number of required arguments of method. What I need is number of optional arguments? e.g.

```
def foo(a,b,c=4,d=3)
  # ...
end
```

How can I identify that there are *2 optional arguments*? Keep in mind this is **Ruby 1.8.7**

**UPDATE**

Apologies question was not clear, I need to know number of optional arguments before calling the method. e.g.

```
method_def = self.instance_method(:foo)
# check for number of args
# call method if it meets some kind of criteria
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. In fact, I think that was one of the reasons for the introduction of `{Proc, Method, UnboundMethod}#parameters` in Ruby 1.9:

```
instance_method(:foo).parameters.count {|type,| type == :opt }
# => 2
```

Comment: From what I have read online, you are probably right. I will wait some more to see if somebody has workaround for that.

Comment: So, I guess that green checkbox means you have given up ;-)

Comment: Yap, there is a pretty strong consensus on this one :) I will have to monkey patch ... but oh well that needs to happen sometimes as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your method like:

```
def foo(a,b,*p)
  number_of_arguments = p.size

  c = p[0]
  d = p[1]      
end
```

Further information can be found [here](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/method-arguments-in-ruby/) under "Optional Arguments".

Comment: @the OP, These are commonly called "splat arguments", which may be useful for googling.

Comment: You can also do this: `c, d = p`. Much shorter :)

Comment: Updated the question, to be more specific apologies.